# How to fix Module Not Found Exception in WildFly 9.0.1

Tags: mysql, wildfly

I am getting this exception while trying to start my app on the WildFly 9.0.1 Final release. My WAR file consists only of an application that builds on Spring Framework. My server log file is below.

```
12:53:57,109 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main:org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: WFLYSRV0179:

Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main at 
org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) at 

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: 
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.mysql:main at 
org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1042) at 
org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1398) at 
org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1426) at 
org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:238) at 
org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadServic
e.java:68) ... 5 more 12:53:57,115 ERROR 

[org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads 
- 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" 
=> "SpringExample.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.SpringExample.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service

 jboss.module.service.\"deployment.SpringExample.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: 
Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.mysql:main"}} 12:53:57,199 
INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "SpringExample.war" (runtime-name : "SpringExample.war") 12:53:57,200 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report 
WFLYCTL0185: Newly corrected services: service jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main (new available) WFLYCTL0186: Services which failed to start: service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: 
Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main 12:54:57,515 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment SpringExample.war (runtime-name: SpringExample.war) in 51ms 12:54:57,516 INFO 
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "SpringExample.war" (runtime-name: "SpringExample.war") 12:54:58,966 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) at 
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.mysql:main at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1042) at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1398) at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1426) at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:238) at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68) ... 5 more 12:54:58,969 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.SpringExample.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.SpringExample.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.mysql:main"}} 12:54:59,002 
INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "SpringExample.war" with deployment "SpringExample.war" 12:54:59,002 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report WFLYCTL0184: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringExample.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE] WFLYCTL0186: Services which failed to start: service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 
jboss.module.service."deployment.SpringExample.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.SpringExample.war:main
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundException: com.mysql

Comment: Your war file is trying to reference the module "com.mysql:main".  It appears that this isn't deployed to your container.

Comment: Actually, WildFly will not have mysql as a module by default,  in your case.   1) You might configured a data source with MySQL in standalone.xml and given the module name as "coom.mysql". Since there there is no module with "com.mysql" it is throwing the above exception.  Please follow the steps given iin the below link for correct data source configuration.  https://sheemoul.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/configure-mysql-datasource-in-wildfly-8-0/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to look module concept of WildFly on [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Defining+a+module). Moreover, [defining mySQL module link](http://giordanomaestro.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/install-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly.htmlhttp://giordanomaestro.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/install-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly.html?m=1) could be helpful.